# TypeScript does not accept points with x being a string for Line chart of time type

Tags: typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using chart.js with the following libraries/versions in my Vite/React project in TypeScript:

- chart.js: 4.3.0
- react-chartjs-2: 5.2.0
- chartjs-adapter-date-fns: 3.0.0
- chartjs-plugin-datalabels: 2.2.0

I'm in a pickle right now because I want to use a Line chart with "time" type, so my datasets' `x` are strings (formatted dates) and my datasets' `y` are numbers.

I tried to be as explicit as I could when declaring the datasets:

```
const data: ChartData<"line", StatPointDto[]> = {
        datasets: [
            {
                ...
                data: props.data.ios,
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
                data: props.data.android,
                ...
            },
        ] as ChartDataset<"line", StatPointDto[]>[],
    };
```

`props.data.ios` and `props.data.android` are both `StatPointDto[]`.

`StatPointDto` is a simple wrapper class that I use in my project, defined as follows:

```
export class StatPointDto {
    public x: string;
    public y: number;

    constructor(x: string, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

My chart is declared as follows, nothing fancy:

```
<Line
    data={chartData}
    options={chartOptions}
/>
```

With this ChartData setup, I get a TypeScript type mismatch error:

```
Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
Type 'StatPointDto[]' is not assignable to type '(number | Point | null)[]'.
Type 'StatPointDto' is not assignable to type 'number | Point | null'.
Type 'StatPointDto' is not assignable to type 'Point'.
Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

By reading, I see that Chart.js wants my dataset elements to be either numbers, `Points`, or nulls.
The `Point` definition of Chart.js has `x` and `y` as numbers but since this is a time series, I have `x` strings, which just does not work.

What can I do to pass my points data properly, considering `x` values are strings (dates) and `y` values are numbers, without being yelled at by TypeScript?

*Note: this is supposed to be allowed, according to https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#typescript*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

My bad, the error was coming from something else, in my case
it was coming from this declaration using the React `useState` hook:

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState<ChartData<"line">>({
    datasets: [],
});
```

Which was incomplete, causing a type inconsistency in my code.
I fixed it by writing:

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState<ChartData<"line", StatPointDto[]>>({
    datasets: [],
});
```